# Query where sum of a group of records greater than ZERO

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to write a query on a trades table where there are buy and sell transactions for various items. Trying to build a query where on a given date I wish to know how many of each item do I hold. That part is achieved.

Now the issue is, the query I have written returns a list of items which were once bought, and sold already, so on a given date that item shows 0 as balance. I want to avoid all items with zero balance as of that particular date.

My query looks like this.

```
Select 
    I.itemName, I.iID, 
    sum(case when Tr.Buy=1 then Tr.qty when Tr.Buy=0 then Tr.qty*-1 else 0 end) as TotalQty 
from 
    Trades Tr, ItemMast I
where 
    Tr.iID = I.iID 
    and I.iCode = '1253'
    and Tr.tDate <= '5/13/2015' 
group by 
    I.itemName, I.iID
order by 
    I.itemName, I.iID
```

I tried to modify the where clause adding `Where TotalQty > 0`, but it does not work.

Not sure how to go about with this. I am trying to build this on SQL Server CE.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for `HAVING`.

Comment: You could also wrap your existing query in brackets, give it in alias, and then select from that: select * from ( <query> ) x where x.TotalQty > 0

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use full expression in `having` clause as below

```
Select I.itemName, I.iID, sum(case when Tr.Buy=1 then Tr.qty when Tr.Buy=0 then Tr.qty*-1 else 0 end) as TotalQty 
from Trades Tr,ItemMast I
where Tr.iID = I.iID 
and I.iCode = '1253'
and Tr.tDate<= '5/13/2015' 
group by I.itemName, I.iID
having sum(case when Tr.Buy=1 then Tr.qty when Tr.Buy=0 then Tr.qty*-1 else 0 end) > 0
order by I.itemName, I.iID
```